# Db performance improvement

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I am creating a database and a project. In this project we will create different-different companies. We have two options for create database.

1. Create a common table for all companies and save all information in a single table. Suppose company_daily_records which will have all companies data. Suppose a company have 1,00,000 records and we have 1000 companies so this company_daily_records will have 1,00,000*1000 records
2. Create separate db table for each company so their will be 1000 company_daily_records tables and each table will have 1,00,000 records.

Which db performance will be good,

Also which db SQL language we should prefer?

Comment: I think you are in very initial stage of your design. If you have competency/Skills in nosql databases, then I would suggest you to go ahead with  any document based no sql database. That should be good for this scenario.
you can have partitions by company name in that db. Ideal case

Answer (score 0):

1) if you create separate database for each company, which is more likely, then your record will be organized. But if your project deal with all companies at the same time then you have to switch your connection frequently.

2) if you create one database for all companies, it is possible also you just have to add a additional table of 'company' includes all companies that can be used as foreign_key in e.g 'employee' table to separate employees from specific company...
But it has complexity of records as its not in very organized form.

As you mention the daily record can be in billions, I suggest you to go with separate databases that will surely save searching, query time which is the most important aspect...

--> I think you can use mysql to manage your record.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest create a table for each companies because:

- How do you know what/how many companies there will be?
- When you have a new company, you would possibly need to create a new table in database, and update your application code manually. It could be made automatic, but not an easy task though

Because you are at the early state now, it is fine to with the traditional way of relational database. That is to a `company` table a `company_record` table. You can worry about performance later when it happens or when you have spare time for optimization

Answer (score 0):

Don't design the schema for a large dataset until you have some thoughts on how how the data will be inserted and queried.

You need to avoid scanning 100 million (10 crore) rows to get an answer; it will be painfully slow.  That implies indexing.

NoSQL implies no indexing, or you have to build the indexes yourself.  You would be better off with a real RDBMS doing such heavy-lifting for you.

If you split by company into tables or databases or partitions or shards:

- Today you have 1000 tables (etc), tomorrow you have 1123.
- Any operation that goes across companies will be difficult and slow.
- Working with 1000 tables/dbs/partition, or especially shards, has inefficiencies.

I vote for a single 'large' (but not 'huge') table with a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2-bytes) column for `company_id`.

Since you are into the "Data Warehouse" realm, Summary Tables come to mind.

Will you be deleting "old" data?  That is another thing to worry about in large tables.

Inserting 1000 rows per *day* is no problem.  (1000/second would be another story.)